# Sass breakpoint doesn't work

Tags: sass, media-queries, compass-sass, breakpoint-sass

I've checked all possibilities, and haven't seen any issue.

```
config.rb
```

Have following line: `require 'breakpoint'`

```
style.scss
```

also `@import "breakpoint";`

I'm trying this way:

```
$medium: 96rem; // or even $medium: 51rem 96rem;

.any-class{
    @include breakpoint($medium);
    //change any property
}
```

I don't see any effect in compiled css file, only new properties which overrides previous ones.
I'm using `Sass 3.4.13 (Selective Steve)` and `Compass 1.0.1 (Polaris)`.

Edit:
Sample compilation result:

```
//Sass
html{
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
body{
    @include breakpoint(100rem);
    background-color: #000;
}
```

compiled:

```
//Css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
body {
}
body {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: `rem` isn't a valid unit for media queries, so they won't work.

Comment: @Snugug Sure it is, try it for yourself.  It validates, too.

Comment: @Snugug I've tried rem in normal media queries and it work's fine.

Comment: @cimmanon It's not duplicate. In my case breakpoint doesn't work, no matter what I provide - 1000 [unit] or without unit. I don't have any compilation errors also.

Comment: That's why I'm asking for the compiled results.

Comment: @cimmanon added compilation result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using the mixin incorrectly.  The breakpoint mixin is a `@content` aware mixin, the styles intended for that mixin need to be placed inside curly braces:

```
body{
    @include breakpoint(100rem) {
      background-color: #000;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
@media (min-width: 100rem) {
  body {
    background-color: #000;
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh god, this example http://breakpoint-sass.com/ isn't proper for blind peoples! :) I didn't noticed those curly braces... Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, the contrast is really bad on that syntax highlighting, you can barely see the curly braces.